# Mailchimp Oauth token API 400 returns error invalid_client

Tags: oauth-2.0, backend

I'm having trouble with Mailchimp token API. I've worked with OAuth a lot, but it seems something is not wokring with this API. Providing I've obtained authorization code from callback, the request to get token is like this:

URL: https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token
Method: POST
Body
`grant_type`: "authorization_code"
`client_id`: client_id
`client_secret`: client_secret
`redirect_uri`: redirect_uri
`code`: code

client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri are exactly from Mailchimp Registered App configuration. I basically copy paste those 3 values to ensure valid information. And the response is

```
Bad request 400
{
  "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

I tried to send from server, from curl, from Postman. Still the same error. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with Python Requests.  I was using `urlencode` on the dictionary data it was sent through the request:

```
Params = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_url,
        }
params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

tokenResponse = requests.post(access_token_url, data=params)
```

Once I removed the `urlencode` it worked:

```
Params = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': code,
            'redirect_uri': redirect_url,
        }
tokenResponse = requests.post(access_token_url, data=params)
```

I am by no means an expert in Oauth2 so I'm not sure why this worked.  I thought when I read the documentation it stated that the POST was x-www-form-urlencoded, so I urlencoded the data.  Make sure your body is in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

I believe my issue was rare but could possibly help someone else. When I initially setup my integration app, seconds after the mailchimp servers went down. when the servers came back up I received "invalid client" countless times. Nothing worked, the only solution was to create a brand new app, once i did this it started working.

Because this is a generic error message from mailchimp i thought i was sending my request improperly, however the client was in fact invalid. When in doubt swap it out!

Comment: The servers didn't go down, but registering a new app and using  the new credentials worked for me.